# local variable might be referenced before assignment in Python

Tags: python

I'm going through some code that implements a decision tree learner.
Here is the code:

```
def calculate_entropy(self, tags):

    tags_counter = Counter()

    if len(tags) > 0:
        for tag in tags:
            tags_counter[tag] += 1
            classes_probs = [float(tags_counter[tag]) / len(tags) for tag in tags_counter]

        entropy = 0
        for prob in classes_probs:
            if prob == 0:
                return 0
            entropy -= prob * math.log(prob, 2)

        return entropy

    else:
        return 0
```

My questions are:

1. for classes_probs I get a local variable might be referenced before assignment message, and I can't figure why.
2. what does the code on the right side of the placement into classes probs do? I haven't seen anything like it.

Comment: You have not included everything to reproduce the issue you are facing. Edit the post to include what error your facing, input values and expected output

Comment: To your second question, it's a _list comprehension_

Comment: BTW, we generally require a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I stumbled over your problem point as I was voting to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

(1) The warning is because `classes_probs` may be undefined at that point.  If `tags` is empty, the first loop doesn't execute.  You can "fix" this by assigning an empty list before the first loop.

(2) This is called a `list comprehension`.  Use that search term and find a tutorial at your preferred level of writing and examples.

Comment: can you please tell me what will be the "regular" equivalent to the list comprehension in this case?

Comment: Again, "use that search term".  Stack Overflow is not intended as a replacement for existing tutorials and individual research.

Comment: my apologies :-)

Comment: `[float(tags_counter[tag]) / len(tags) for tag in tags_counter]` could be written 'regularly' as:
`l = []`
`for tag in tags_counter:`
`l.append(float(tags_counter[tag]) / len(tags)))`